# How to reolve Aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM TRIALTABLE1
```

Output :

```
        PRODUCTNAME     PRICE
        BMW            2000000
        Yamaha R15     125000 
        Splendour Plus 60000 
        BMW            7000000
```

Query #2:

```
select * from TRIALTABLE2
```

Output:

```
        SRNO    PRODUCTNAME
         1      Splendour Plus 
         2        BMW
```

If my query is static as

```
select 
    PRODUCTNAME, sum(CASE when PRODUCTNAME='BMW' then 10 else 0 END ) as ID 
from TRIALTABLE1 
group by PRODUCTNAME
```

it works.. But If I use dynamic PRODUCTNAME for BMW, it throws error..

```
select 
   PRODUCTNAME, sum(CASE when PRODUCTNAME= (SELECT PRODUCTNAME FROM TRIALTABLE2 WHERE SRNO=2) then 10 else 0 END ) as ID 
from TRIALTABLE1
group by PRODUCTNAME
```

Error:

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

How should I resolve this problem ?

Comment: cannot read, please format to separate code from text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from your sample, it seems that you just need a left join to avoid the subquery ?

```
select t1.productname,
       sum (case when t2.srno= 2 then 10 else 0 end) as ID
from trialtable1 t1
left join trialtable2 t2 on t2.productname= t1.productname
group by t1.productname
```

Comment: Thanks Raphaël Althaus, It worked.. But I still didn't get what was the problem with that ?

Comment: @SonalPM well, as mentioned in the error message, you can't do a SUM on a subquery

Answer (score 1):

As a note, you can write this query as:

```
select distinct PRODUCTNAME,
       (SELECT sum(case when srno = 2 then 10 else 0 end)
        FROM TRIALTABLE2 t2
        WHERE t2.PRODUCTNAME = t1.PRODUCTNAME
       ) as ID
from TRIALTABLE1;
```

This is to emphasize that although you cannot use a subquery inside an aggregation function, you can use an aggregation function inside a subquery.

Comment: Correct, But the Result is not grouped together by this query, it makes different entry for PRODUCTNAME and Its Price

Comment: @SonalPM . . . This did assume that `productid` is unique in `trialtable1`, which I thought was true when I read the question but I missed the two BMW values.  In any case, the selected answer is correct, but I wanted to show a method similar to your original approach.